# Error for picture already exist and not printing results of my count to a file

Tags: shell, command

Im working on this homework and trying to figure out why I get this error and it wont print my count to the associated file(?) [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SMpn.png)e [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/554Bj.png)

Comment: Please paste _code_ and _error outputs_ as text, not as image! So anyone can copy and reproduce the [example]. A complete and easy to read question **increases your chances to get an answer** 

Comment: If you're in fear of your teacher searching, then rename parts to be anonymous (so do company employees who don't want to disclose internal secrets). You can copy text in seconds, we'll need minutes to read and type from your screenshots 

Comment: Do you use `find` just to count them by filetype?

Comment: @MrClick: Your solution is almost on the table here. Please apply what [you learned on the sister-site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557405/counting-files-image-and-log-into-a-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this construction with `awk` you can use sample:

```
echo "PNG file" $(ls -1 PNG|wc -l) >> PictureCount.md
```

and you will get the number of files in this directory.

BTW I do not see any info about `wc -1`

Comment: Ill give it a try! Thank you for your answer

Comment: I was actually using:

Comment: find JPG -type -iname '*.jpg' | wc -l >> PictureCount.md               but that was not working

Comment: also using your code, is it normal in VSC for the code to turn orange at the $ to the ending ) ? Mine is orange

Comment: I appreciate your help and thank you, it worked perfectly!!

Comment: @MrClick, if you are happy with my answer feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer :)